# Does the File.Copy(source, dest) lock the file?

Tags: c#

Does the File.Copy(source, dest) lock the file while copying? While one file is being copied in one thread, can second thread start copying the same file to a DIFFERENT dest?

Thanks,

Comment: Reads don't generally lock. So, source should be readable by others. Dest should be locked though as it is being written.

Comment: I really suggest you change your username. SO is not 4chan :)

Comment: you have express confusion over word of LOCK. how LOCK? is THREAD-lock? is file-lock? is reader writer lock? what is LOCK you want for use ?

Comment: @PRASHANT P, I meant File Lock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple thread can access the file in read only mode simultaneously while one thread is copying the file. Multiple copy operation can be performed simultaneously for the same file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can :) it's like your copying the same file to diffrent folders on windows.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no lock and multiple thread should be able to call it just fine.